# measuring possible water volumes with two bottle with size a b

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have two bottles A, B for filling water, with size a and b. With the following operations being allowed, what is the set of all possible volumes we can get?

Suppose  a < b, then all possible operations are:

1. fully fill A
2. fully fill B
3. if A, B has water with volumes x, y respectively, fill A with water in B, resulting in volumes x+y, 0 or a, x+y-a, that two cases corresponding to x+y < a and x+y > a
4. similar to operations 3, but in the other direction.

I think that if (a,b) = 1, then all volumes less than a is possible to measure. But no idea to prove this. Maybe it’s related to the Euclidean’s algorithm for finding greatest common divisor. any hints? Thanks!

For example take a=9 and b=4 and try to measuring 6: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/measuring-6l-water-4l-9l-buckets/

Comment: Use [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), so $ra-sb=(a,b)$ for some $r,s>0$. You can repeatedly fill up B from A; also empty B any time it is full, and fill up A from the tap any time it is empty. Eventually after having filled A $r$ times and filled B $s$ times you will have (a,b) left in A.

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.